# Excel Macro: Between Named Rows, Cell to Equal Zero if Another Cell = "c"

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in Columns H, I and J between two named rows, "BorderFirstRow" at the top and "BorderLastRow" at the bottom.  I'm using the named rows because the number of rows in between is always changing as information is added or deleted.

I'm trying to create a macro with a section that sets a value of zero in the H, I and J cells if the correlating cell of the same row in Column AA = "c"

I haven't tried anything because I'm really at a loss as to where to start since I'm not good with fluctuating data ranges.  I've used the following to set the range in the past when I was looking to sort the data but not sure if it is applicable as a solution?

```
With .Range(.Cells(.Range("BorderFirstRow").Row + 1, "H"), _
         .Cells(.Range("BorderLastRow").Row - 1, "J"))
```

Comment: You did not explain to much in your question. Is "BorderLastRow" named cell on the last row of the sheet? I mean, after its row there are not any other filled cells. If yes, there are other simple ways to set the range. Then, what do you want accomplishing? If a cell in column A:A has value equal to "c", should the cells in range H:J, the same row to be zero? Is this the only task your code should accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Range Between to Named Row Ranges

- That's a great idea.
- Just adjust the workbook and the worksheet name if necessary.

**The Code**

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = .Range("BorderFirstRow").Row + 1 To .Range("BorderLastRow").Row - 1
        If .Cells(i, "AA").Value = "c" Then
            .Columns("H:J").Rows(i).Value = 0
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Oh wow, that worked perfectly!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You did not answer my clarification question...

Please, check the next code. It will work if the assumption from my above comment is true:

```
Sub ChangeH_JValuesForCInAA()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arr, i As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 arr = sh.Range(sh.cells(sh.Range("BorderFirstRow").row, "A"), sh.cells(sh.Range("BorderLastRow").row, "J")).Value
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 1) = "c" Then
        arr(i, 8) = 0: arr(i, 9) = 0: arr(i, 10) = 0
    End If
 Next i
 sh.cells(sh.Range("BorderFirstRow").row, "A").Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
End Sub
```